# powershell - get display name from person or group type field

Tags: powershell

The following code gives me the domain\username but I need to get the display name of the user. any idea?

```
$($item["Manager_Name"])
```

Thanks

Comment: This post helped solved the issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549037/sharepoint-powershell-how-to-get-person-fields-display-name

Answer (score 2):

This post helped solved the issue.

```
$Manager = $item["Manager_Name"]
$ManagerObj = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue($web, $Manager)
$ManagerDisplayName = $ManagerObj.User.DisplayName
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549037/sharepoint-powershell-how-to-get-person-fields-display-name

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-SPUser -web http://server/sites/yoursite -Identity "yourdomain\mike" | Select ID, UserLogin, DisplayName
```

Comment: This did not work when I put it inside the code.